# Sizing video to be browser window background

Tags: css, html, video

The dimensions of my video are 1280 × 720.

I was wondering if it is possible to stretch the video so that it will fit into the size of my browser or other browsers depending on an aspect ratio.

I am using the video tag to place a video on the background of my page. I currently have the video playing in the background but I do not know how to size it appropriately.

I would provide a jsfiddle but I'm not sure how to upload my local video to test recreate this situation

Comment: if you can, create a JSFiddle or post the codes that you used for the video and the section

Comment: @XahedKamal I'm not sure how to upload my video file onto jsfiddle. Tried finding an alternative but having trouble finding one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you are looking for...

**CSS**

```
#video-bg {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
}
#video-bg > video {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
/* 1. No object-fit support: */
@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
   #video-bg > video { height: 300%; top: -100%; }
}
@media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
   #video-bg > video { width: 300%; left: -100%; }
}
/* 2. If supporting object-fit, overriding (1): */
   @supports (object-fit: cover) {
   #video-bg > video {
   top: 0; left: 0;
   width: 100%; height: 100%;
   object-fit: cover;
 }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="video-bg">
    <video controls loop>
    <source type="video/mp4" src="video.mp4">
    <source type="video/webm" src="video.webm">
    </video>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ravikumar8/c0v6nrt9/)